# Writing to XML from JavaScript using asp or aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, asp-classic

I am writing a bookmarklet that pops up a form and allows users to select xml files.  I am reading the file using:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://localhost/products/dataSource.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function (xml) {
       $(xml).find('node').each(function () {
           //get values from xml file         
       });       
   }
});
```

This works well.

My problem is that I want to edit and add to the xml and I understand that JavaScript cannot directly write to the file for security reasons.

I understand that I can write to the xml file using an asp or .aspx page.

Is this still the best way to achieve writing to the xml file and what would the code look like?

I'm looking for the simplest way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right. You can't do that in javascript since it is being executed in the browser on the client. You should do this in asp.net code behind. You can call the c# method with ajax if it helps. In c# you can do it with `XDocument`.

Comment: Thanks,do you know of a link with an example?

Comment: Do you mean an example of XDocument?